# How to get my module to work globally? Is there any config in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a very simple module that I want to use globally. I have already published it to npm as `gammarouter-api`.

1. I would like to know how can I test the module globally before publishing to npm (is `npm link` the answer?)
2. I noticed that all the modules that I install globally (I have no problems using any third party modules globally) goes to the folder `/user/local/lib/node_module` BUT my path does not contains this folder but `/usr/local/bin`, where I can find some files related to the global installed modules.

   When I install my module with `npm install -g gammarouter-api` the folder `gammarouter-api` is created at `/user/local/lib/node_module` but nothing goes to `/usr/local/bin`, thats why its unreachable. Is there any setting/configuration/trick for this to work?

Comment: 1. Do you mean `npm install . -g` (from with in the app root dir)?

Comment: 2. have you added the scripts in the "bin" property in you package.json? See https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#bin

Comment: Hi @AndreasHultgren - 1. I mean a way for testing the package globally without having to publish to npm, 2. Thank you for the link, didn't know the property "bin" existed that will surely solve my second problem!

Comment: `npm install . -g` means that you want to install the current directory globally, it doesn't have to be published for you to do that. It's even [recommended in the docs](https://npmjs.org/doc/developers.html#Before-Publishing-Make-Sure-Your-Package-Installs-and-Works) that you do that.

Comment: yes, great! now it works!!! Also didn't know about `npm install . -g`, awesome... @AndreasHultgren I suggest you rewriting your comments as a single answer so I can accept. I also needed to insert `#!/usr/bin/env node` at the top of my script for it to work! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `npm install . -g` in the root of a module to install it globally. [See the docs](https://npmjs.org/doc/developers.html#Before-Publishing-Make-Sure-Your-Package-Installs-and-Works).
2. The `bin` property in you package.json is used to specify which executables should be added to the PATH. [See the docs](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#bin).

For example:

```
{
  "name": "my-module",
  "bin": "./bin/script.js"
}
```